# How do I create Oracle Type which refers to table columns for data type?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I am trying to define a `type` using the following code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE AS OBJECT (
    app_id        some_table_name.app_id%type
);
```

If I run this, I get the error.

```
Error(4,32): PLS-00201: identifier 'some_table_name.app_id' must be declared
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: More details on this [Oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2269924). Makes sense I guess but it did seem to me to be something I intuitively wanted to do for best practice.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What's wrong with it is that `%type` is PL/SQL syntax.  It isn't supported in SQL. Now we use PL/SQL to define Types (especially member functions, constructors, etc) but the Types themselves are SQL objects, and so follow SQL rules. That means we must declare Type attributes with explicit datatypes.

I agree that's a shame, and it would be really neat if we could reference table columns in type declarations like this.  Unfortunately Oracle have really slowed down the changes to their TYPE implementation over the last couple of versions, so I think it is unlikely this will change in the near future.

What I would *really* like to see is Oracle support this syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE AS OBJECT 
      (     one_row        some_table_name.%rowtype );
```

Dynamic objects for interfaces: how cool would that be?

Comment: `%type` is PL/SQL syntax - This was the important bit I missed. Thanks.

Comment: +1, it is a shame and would make coding for this sort of `TYPE` more flexible.

Comment: They'd have to track the dependencies like they do in views and packages; given how terminally buggered Oracle's type implementation is, I'll put that under "never gonna happen."

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `some_table_name.app_id%type` when declaring a type in the database, any more than you can do this:

```
create table emp (empno number,
                  deptno dept.deptnp%type, -- NOT ALLOWED
                 );
```

You must use either a built-in type such as NUMBER, VARCHAR2(10) or a user-defined type such as `mytype`