# Pl/SQL Create Global Type using %rowtype for attributes

Tags: types, plsql, rowtype

is it possible to declare an Attribute with %ROWTYPE in a global Type?

`create or replace TYPE test_type AS OBJECT (
   variable_test test_table%ROWTYPE,
   MEMBER FUNCTION get_ID RETURN NUMBER;)`

Comment: Try to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607313/assign-value-to-a-field-of-rowtype-where-field-name-is-a-string

Comment: See this on: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634535/how-do-i-create-oracle-type-which-refers-to-table-columns-for-data-type)